# Imposing orders on distributions based on Wilcoxon test

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I am trying to figure out part of a text I am reading about [non parametric tests](https://www.nature.com/articles/nmeth.2937).

In there it is stated that:

> The fact that the output of a rank test is driven by the probability that a value drawn from distribution A will be smaller (or larger) than one drawn from B without regard to their absolute difference has an interesting consequence: we cannot use this probability (pairwise preferences, in general) to impose an order on distributions.

To exemplify this point, the following example is given:

> Consider a case of three equally prevalent diseases for which treatment A has cure times of 2, 2 and 5 days for the three diseases, and treatment B has 1, 4 and 4. Without treatment, each disease requires 3 days to cure—let's call this control C. Treatment A is better than C for the first two diseases but not the third, and treatment B is better only for the first. Can we determine which of the three options (A, B, C) is better? If we try to answer this using the probability of observing a shorter time to cure, we find P(A < C) = 67% and P(C < B) = 67% but also that P(B < A) = 56%—a rock-paper-scissors scenario.

Both parts have left me wondering what is really the meaning of this idea, specially when it is simplified to a *rock-paper-scissors scenario*

I would have liked to be able to share what I think it means, but after almost two hours, I am still clueless.

Comment: A relationship of the form $P(A>B)>\frac12$ is not transitive. Let's say you denote two random variables like that as $A\succ B$. Then if you have $A\succ B$ and $B\succ C$, it is NOT necessarily the case that $A\succ C$. e.g. see the example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontransitive_dice#Example). If you have two sets of data like that (but many observations, enough that you get a significant Wilcoxon test statistic) you may be tempted to say that A is "larger than" B (in some sense), and then that B is "larger than" C, and then that C is "larger than" A, but clearly $A\nsucc$ itself